# php `connect() failed` on centos 7.3

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I am deploying a php project on centos `7.3` , there is an error `connect() failed` .

`nginx` and `php` and `mariadb` has been running,and I can access the welcome page of nginx.

```
[root@demo ~]# systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep enabled
//...
mariadb.service                               enabled 
mysql.service                                 enabled 
mysqld.service                                enabled 
nginx.service                                 enabled 
php-fpm.service                               enabled 
//...
```

Then,I upload a php project to this centos server.

nginx configuration is like this: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /var/www/project/public;
    #fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

php configuration is like this: `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
#listen = /run/php-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`：

```
//error of using `unix:/run/php-fpm.sock`：
connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:"

//error of `using 127.0.0.1:9000`：
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

What should I do?

Comment: `nginx` is not running, or it's misconfigured. Check with `sudo service --status-all` to make sure there's a plus sign next to nginx, and try restarting it.

Comment: Did you restart `php-fpm`? `systemctl restart php-fpm`. Also add output of `systemctl status php-fpm`, `sudo lsof -c php-fpm -a -i4`